# Database Time comparison for whenever gem cron job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I am writing a whenever runner defined in the Schedule model like this;

```
def self.scheduled_jobs   
    jobs = Schedule.where(execution_time <= Time.now )
      if !jobs.nil?
      jobs.each do |job|
        task = Schedule.find(job)
        MessageWorker.perform_async(task.message_id, task.lists, task.user_id)
        task.destroy
      end
   end
end
```

There is something wrong with the query here;

`jobs = Schedule.where(execution_time <= Time.now )`

And advice on how i can write it well?

in the console the response is ;

`NameError: undefined local variable or method`execution_time' for main:Object`

Overall any advice on how to improve the code?

The whenever cron job is here;

```
set :output, "/log/cron_log.log"
every 5.minute do
   runner "Schedule.scheduled_jobs"
end
```

Comment: replace `where` condition with `"execution_time <= ?", Time.now`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the column `execution_time` does exist, try this:

```
Schedule.where('execution_time <= ?', Time.now)
```

On a side note:

It seems you are passing in `task.lists` to the worker, but shouldn't that be `task.list_ids`? Passing model objects to a worker is bad practice, pass ids instead.

Comment: lists is actually just carry IDs. Thank you